# How do you code a self-updating class variable in python

Tags: python, class, object

```
class CLASS:
    var_total = 0
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var
        CLASS.var_total+=var

obj_one = CLASS(48)
obj_two = CLASS(74)
obj_three = CLASS(12)
```

I don't want the `var_total` to be static, how do you code it to update automatically as the `var` property of the `objects` changes later in the code?

Comment: do you mean, update as in sum or update as in most recent?

Comment: Every day the properties of the objects will change, I need them to display the updated total daily.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than create different instances with **init**, why not create one and use the method.

```
class MyClass:
    total= 0

    def add_prop(self,var):
       self.total += var
 

obj = MyClass()
obj.add_prop(48
obj.add_prop(78)
obj.add_prop(12)
obj.total #124
```

or if you need to grab the value later in your code

```
class myclass:
    total= 0
    var = 0 
    def var_data(self,var):
        self.var= var
        self.totaladd(var)

    def totaladd(self,value):
       self.total +=  value
```